# Trying to find the parent of a node in a binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a function that finds the parent of a given node in a binary tree, but the function always returns the root node. I have no idea how to make it work. I've been trying for days.

```
Tree* NodeParent(Tree* a, char c)
{
    Tree *parent = a;

    if (!EmptyTree(a))
    {
        if ((!EmptyTree(a->Left) && info(a->Left) == c)
            || (!EmptyTree(a->Right) && info(a->Right) == c))
            return parent = a;

        else
        {
            NodeParent(a->Left, c);
            NodeParent(a->Right, c);
        }
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Also, the tree structure

```
struct tree
{
    char c;
    Tree* Left;
    Tree* Right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        return parent = a;
```

is not C (or at least, it's not what you think C does here).

You just want something like

```
return a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the return value of your recursive calls to `NodeParent(a->Left, c)` and `NodeParent(a->Right, c)`... You could try something like this:

```
Tree* NodeParent(Tree* a, char c) {
    Tree *parent;

    // a is empty tree -> return NULL
    if (EmptyTree(a)) {
        return NULL;

    // in this case, a is the parent
    } else if ((!EmptyTree(a->Left) && info(a->Left) == c)
        || (!EmptyTree(a->Right) && info(a->Right) == c)) {
        return a;

    // search to the left
    } else if ((parent = NodeParent(a->Left, c)) != NULL) {
        return parent;

    // search to the right
    } else if ((parent = NodeParent(a->Right, c)) != NULL) {
        return parent;

    // c not found in sub-trees
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```